# JQGrid - toggling multiselect

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to toggle the `multiselect` option of a grid?

Changing the `multiselect` parameter of the grid and calling for a reload has the side-effect of leaving the header behind when disabling or not creating the header column if `multiselect` was not `TRUE` upon the grid creation.

The closest I have come is setting `multiselect` to `TRUE` upon grid creation and using `showCol` and `hideCol` to `toggle: $('#grid').showCol("cb").trigger('reloadGrid');`

This has a side effect of changing the grid width when toggled. It appears the cb column width is reserved when it is not hidden.

Basically I'm attempting to create a grid with an "edit/cancel" button to toggle the `multiselect` -- very similar to how the iPhone/iPad handles deleting `multiple` mail or text messages.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I full agree with Justin that jqGrid don't support toggling of `multiselect` parameter dynamically. So +1 to his answer in any way. I agree, that the simplest and the only supported way to toggle `multiselect` parameter will be connected with re-initialize (re-creating) the grid.

So if you need to change the value of `multiselect` parameter of jqGrid you need first change `multiselect` parameter with respect of respect `setGridParam` and then re-creating the grid with respect of [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) method for example. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RecreateGrid.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4232168/315935).

Nevertheless I find your question very interesting (+1 for you too). It's a little sport task at least to try to implement the behavior.

Some remarks for the understanding the complexity of the problem. During filling of the body of the grid jqGrid code calculate positions of the cells based on the value of `multiselect` parameter (see setting of `gi` value [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/grid.base.js#L1294) and usage it later, [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/grid.base.js#L1309) for example). So if you will hide the column 'cb', which hold the checkboxes, the cell position will be calculated wrong. **The grid will be filled correctly only if either the column 'cb' not exists at all or if you have `multiselect: true`**. So you have to set `multiselect: true` *before* paging or sorting of the grid if the column 'cb' exist in the grid. Even for hidden column 'cb' you have to set `multiselect` to `true`. On the other side you have to set `multiselect` to the value which corresponds the real behavior which you need *directly after* filling of the grid (for example in the `loadComplete`).

I hope I express me clear inspite of my bad English. To be sure that all understand me correctly I repeat the same one more time. If you want try to toggle `multiselect` dynamically you have to do the following steps:

- create grid in any way with `multiselect: true` to have 'cb' column
- set `multiselect: false` and hide 'cb' column in the `loadComplete` if you want to have single select behavior
- set `multiselect: true` always *before* refreshing the grid: before paging, sorting, filtering, reloading and so on.

I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideMultiselectColumn.htm) which seems to work. It has the button which can be used to toggle `multiselect` parameter:

[image]

In the demo I used the trick with subclassing (overwriting of the original event handle) of `reloadGrid` event which I described [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4078683/315935).

The most important parts of the code from the demo you will find below:

```js
var events, originalReloadGrid, $grid = $("#list"), multiselect = false,
    enableMultiselect = function (isEnable) {
        $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', {multiselect: (isEnable ? true : false)});
    };

$grid.jqGrid({
    // ... some parameters
    multiselect: true,
    onPaging: function () {
        enableMultiselect.call(this, true);
    },
    onSortCol: function () {
        enableMultiselect.call(this, true);
    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        if (!multiselect) {
            $(this).jqGrid('hideCol', 'cb');
        } else {
            $(this).jqGrid('showCol', 'cb');
        }
        enableMultiselect.call(this, multiselect);
    }
});
$grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {add: false, edit: false, del: false}, {}, {}, {},
    {multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true, closeOnEscape: true, showQuery: true, closeAfterSearch: true});

events = $grid.data("events"); // read all events bound to
// Verify that one reloadGrid event hanler is set. It should be set
if (events && events.reloadGrid && events.reloadGrid.length === 1) {
    originalReloadGrid = events.reloadGrid[0].handler; // save old
    $grid.unbind('reloadGrid');
    $grid.bind('reloadGrid', function (e, opts) {
        enableMultiselect.call(this, true);
        originalReloadGrid.call(this, e, opts);
    });
}

$("#multi").button().click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    multiselect = $this.is(":checked");
    $this.button("option", "label", multiselect ?
                "To use single select click here" :
                "To use multiselect click here");
    enableMultiselect.call($grid[0], true);
    $grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
});
```

**UPDATED**: In case of usage jQuery in version 1.8 or higher one have to change the line `events = $grid.data("events");` to `events = $._data($grid[0], "events");`. One can find the modified demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HideMultiselectColumn_.htm).

Comment: @JustinEthier -- But you didn't +1 him :)

Comment: @david - Neither did you :). Sorry about that, it was a busy day - +1 to Oleg now.

Comment: Same here -- I would give you a +1 but I can't. Thank you very much.

Comment: After implimenting the code in your demo, I found your demo exibits the same same issue my code has (I'm assuming your code addresses issues that I have not yet come across so I'll stick with yours). If you add "autowidth:true" to your demo I think you will see the problem I am having. When the grid is inteneded to fill the entire div or page, it does not when the cb column is hidden. Everything functions properly, just not 100% on the display.

Comment: @user1073957: You are welcome! After having 15 reputation points you will be able to use the most important right on the stackoverflow: to vote about 30 questions or answers per day. It will help other users to find good questions and helpful answers. I think you will archive the 15 points level very soon.

Comment: @user1073957: I personally never use `autowidth: true` property. I prefer to use even `shrinkToFit: false` setting. Nevertheless you can fix the width of the grid if you would use `setGridWidth` and increase or decrease the width on 25 (`$("#list_cb").outerWidth()`) pixel.

Comment: @Shift4SMS: I personally never use `autowidth: true` property. I prefer to use even `shrinkToFit: false` setting. Nevertheless you can fix the width of the grid if you would use `setGridWidth` and increase or decrease the width on 25 (`$("#list_cb").outerWidth()`) pixel.

Answer (score 3):

I really like what you are trying to do here, and think it would be a great enhancement for  jqGrid, but unfortunately this is not officially supported. In the jqGrid documentation under [Documentation | Options | multiselect](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) you can see the `Can be changed?` column for `multiselect` reads:

> No. see HOWTO

It would be nice if there was a link or more information about that HOWTO. Anyway, this is probably why you are running into all of the weird behavior. You may be able to work around it if you try hard enough - if so, please consider posting your solution here.

Alternatively, perhaps you could re-initialize the grid in place and change it from/to a multi-select grid? Not an ideal solution because the user will have to wait longer for the grid to be set up, but this is probably the quickest solution.

Comment: I would give you a +1 but apparently I'm too lowly of a person to be able to vote. Thank you. :-(

Answer (score 0):

A simpler answer:

```
<input type="button" value="Multiselect" onclick="toggle_multiselect()"> 

<script>
function toggle_multiselect()
{
    if ($('#list1 .cbox:visible').length > 0)
    {
        $('#list1').jqGrid('hideCol', 'cb'); 
        jQuery('.jqgrow').click(function(){ jQuery('#list1').jqGrid('resetSelection'); this.checked = true; });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#list1').jqGrid('showCol', 'cb');
        jQuery('.jqgrow').unbind('click');
    }
}
</script>

Where list1 is from <table id="list1"></table>.
```