# How to change multi select dynamically in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid version 4.4.3. I want to change multiselect value with the data or before data dynamically.

It is possible to put dynamic value in multiselect as true or false.

```
jQuery("#plist").jqGrid({
                    url : URL,
                    datatype : 'json',
                    mtype : 'POST',
                    colModel : colModelData,
                    pager : '#pagerTrade',
                    rowNum : 80,
                    gridview: true,
                    rowList : [ 80, 160, 240 ],
                    viewrecords : true,
                    height : "550",
                    width : "auto",
                    viewsortcols : [ true, 'vertical', true ],
                    multiselect : multiselect,
                    multiboxonly: true,
                    autoencode: false,
                });
```

i am calling this code multiple time i want to set multiselect dynamically

Comment: Look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333487/315935)

Comment: Thank you @oleg for quick response.i will try to implement it. Do we have any call back function which calls the server side code even before  calling the actual jqgrid Url and fetches value for multi-select and update it?

Comment: You are welcome! For example `beforeRequest` and `loadBeforeSend`